# Local File Directory for Django

Tags: django, nginx, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I have followed the Digitalocean website tutorial for deploying a Django site. I did it all through the Command Prompt, so all of my files (settings.py, index.html) were accessed through there. Is there a local file directory that I can access so that I can edit all of my files in in a text editor? I also want to easily add CSS files and to the folders. I have to keep on editing on the command prompt.

My main question is: where does django store all of the files created in the Command Prompt then then get uploaded to DigitalOcean? I can't find them on my local drive.

Comment: I use Atom text editor. It works well with python and Django. Especially since you can create a virtual environment and install all your additional packages.

Comment: Django doesn't store anything.  You do that, when you run `django-admin startproject myproject`.  Whatever directory you are currently in what that is ran will be where your project is.